# Replace pattern on pandas series where each row contains list of string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to replace a pattern on a pandas series where each row contains a list of string. The idea is to search for the pattern inside each string which is inside a list and belongs to a row. The dataset has several rows, and this specific columns is composed of a list of strings.

```
input = {'1': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(input)
print(df)
```

Now I would like to replace all 'a' by 'e' in each list of strings in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [118]: df['1'].apply(lambda x: ['e' if v=='a' else v for v in x])
Out[118]:
0    [e, b, c, d]
1    [e, b, c, d]
2    [e, b, c, d]
3    [e, b, c, d]
4    [e, b, c, d]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Another way

```
In [119]: df['1'].apply(lambda x: map(lambda v: 'e' if v=='a' else v, x))
Out[119]:
0    [e, b, c, d]
1    [e, b, c, d]
2    [e, b, c, d]
3    [e, b, c, d]
4    [e, b, c, d]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Or, use `df.applymap(lambdafunc)` on all columns

---

Details

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
              1
0  [a, b, c, d]
1  [a, b, c, d]
2  [a, b, c, d]
3  [a, b, c, d]
4  [a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: Hello Zero, thank you much, your suggestion helped me a lot! :)

Comment: I’d also experiment with compression within compression. +1

Comment: You meant like `[['e' if v=='a' else v for v in x] for x in df['1']]` as in `[[func_part] for x in df['1']]`?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I mean (-:

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun way to do it with [**`dict.get`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) using the default value.  Also using comprehension

```
df['1'] = [[{'a': 'e'}.get(x, x) for x in r] for r in df['1'].values.tolist()]
df

              1
0  [e, b, c, d]
1  [e, b, c, d]
2  [e, b, c, d]
3  [e, b, c, d]
4  [e, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works, but this one does too:

```
input = {'1': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(input)
df = df['1'].apply(lambda x: [v.replace("a", "e") for v in x])
print(df)
```

output:

```
0    [e, b, c, d]
1    [e, b, c, d]
2    [e, b, c, d]
3    [e, b, c, d]
4    [e, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us rebuild the `Dataframe`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'1':df['1'].apply(pd.Series).replace({'a':'e'}).values.tolist()})
df
Out[274]: 
              1
0  [e, b, c, d]
1  [e, b, c, d]
2  [e, b, c, d]
3  [e, b, c, d]
4  [e, b, c, d]
```

Comment: I like this one as well (-:

Comment: Thank you (-; ~~@piRSquared